# How do I return a PBI in a work item query based on 2 conditional related tasks

Tags: tfs

I am using an on-premise version of TFS 2018 and trying to create a work item query that returns me the PBI or BUG work item that has 2 related tasks.

The conditions for the PBI/Bug to be returned are that 1 task is done and the other is NOT done and I do not want the PBI/Bug returned if both tasks are done.

PBI
 - Task1
 - Task2

The query should only return PBI if Task1 is done and Task2 is not done, if both Task1 and Task2 are done then do not return PBI

I was trying to utilise the "work items and direct links" query but also tried various options under the "tree of work items"

Is what I am trying to do even possible or do Task1 and Task 2 have to also have a direct link?
I also tried that but then I only can return tasks, i.e.
return Task2 if it is NOT done but Task1 is done.
I am really after the PBI though

[Attempt at query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83HXR.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not able to achieve this from work item query directly. Since if you use `or` it will return both conditional related  PBI, if you use `and`  if will return none.

You may have to use Rest API or Client API to get all PBI which include child task work items.

Then check each child task's state and compare filter the result.

Another method is using Excel to export them and then filter them in excel.

Comment: Thanks Patrick.
I am just solving my issue now with the direct links between the 2 related tasks and won't worry about the PBI/Bug parent item.